# Plot graph for each row in dataframe and save as jpg format?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':['ABC1','ABC2','ABC3'],
     'A1':[550,350,320],
     'A2':[780,619,567],
     'A3':[520,319,439],
     'A4':[338,312,345],
     'A5':[287, 255, 234],
     'A6':[260,235,232],
     'A7':[235,239,251],
    'Profit':[350,269,270]

})
```

How to plot an individual graph for each ID say, individual graphs for ID's  'ABC1','ABC2','ABC3' having A1, A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7 Profit as Y axis and  ID as X-axis

Sample output on Graph Column on the following spreadsheet.
[image]

Check plotted same data on the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s0vMSw5onvD0VkFXAR8P7WcHAWwE2y7MNkK8eN62y58/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You mean...

```
df.plot(x='id',y=['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','Profit'])
plt.show()
```

Plot with `x` as `'id'` and rest as `y`, it outputs:
[image]

Comment: please check the screenshot on the question